# Ionic trouble with cordova in IOS emulator on fresh project. Keep getting cordova.require is not a function in console log

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I have been banging my head trying to solve this problem.

I've created a blank starter app with Ionic and added no additional plugins.

Whenever I emulate on OSX I get these console errors:

> exeption nativeEvalAndFetch : TypeError: cordova.require is not a
>   function. (In 'cordova.require('cordova/exec')', 'cordova.require' is
>   undefined) com.ionicframework.demo340203: 40784

As well as

> ionic $ 0     176825   log      deviceready has not fired after 5
>   seconds. 1     176828   log      Channel not fired:
>   onCordovaInfoReady.

On another project I get `cordova.define is not a function`.

As is, no plugins work on either the emulator or iPhone. However, if I run the app in ionic view, plugins do work.

Other solutions I've found to similar problems such as not having `cordova.js` in the index file have not helped.

If I use ionic-platform-web-client, I also get the error that Cordova is already defined, even when removing cordova.js from the index file.

Has anyone else dealt with this? Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Since the device ready has not fired your plugins might not have loaded sucessfully.

remove the the ng-app attribute from the html/body tag

Start the angular app after the deviceready:

```
ionic.Platform.ready(function(){
// will execute when device is ready, or immediately if the device is already ready.
var YourAppName = angular.module('YourAppName', []);
 });
```